# Linux local versus UTC time in seconds

Tags: linux, date, datetime, time

Can you please explain what is wrong with these 2 syntax for getting the elapsed time in seconds?

If I run both these commands at the same time:

```
date -u +%s   # - for UTC - returns e.g. 1303430843. 

date +%s     # - for local time - mine is set to pacific time
          # - also returns e.g. 1303430843
```

I get exactly the same number (e.g. 1303430843) of seconds, no difference, yet I would expect 25200 seconds - 7 hours difference, as if I run:

```
date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"    # returns:  2011-04-22 00:01:14

date    "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"    # returns:  2011-04-21 17:01:14 - 7 hours difference
```

What is the catch here?

Thank you

Comment: Unix Timestamp is always in UTC...

Comment: Why you even want to get seconds from 1970-01-01 in your timezone?

Answer (score 5):

From the man page:

> %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

so `%s` returns the time in seconds since a specific point in time specified in UTC, which means it is not affected by timezones at all.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. So if %s format always calculates from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC regardless if -u switch is applied or not, how do I get in a simple way the time in seconds for local (e,g, PST) time?

Comment: @Felix: There's no simple way to do that, because there's really no need for it.

Comment: You can use `date -d '1970-01-01 00:00:00 PST' +%s` to get the time in seconds of that specific point in time and subtract that from `date +%s` to get the current time offset from that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

That is because [GMT uses UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (for the most part they are interchangeable) and PDT is currently [7 hours behind](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst).

To get the current UTC time in seconds:

```
date -u +%s
```

To get the current PDT time in seconds:

```
TZ=":US/Pacific" date +%s
```

Its smart enough to pick up on the DST, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Sorry guys for being slow in getting this. My understanding is that -u switch returns the UTC/GMT time while if I omit it, I get the local time the machine is set to. If both commands:  date %s and: date -u %s return the same number of seconds, can you please tell me how do I get the current time in seconds for UTC and for PST on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

There is not catch. The clock is set and runs UTC. The date command takes into account the local time zone and day light savings into account. This is so you can display the date/time for any time zone in the world.

Comment: Thank you Ad, I understand that, that is why I expect some difference in the commands:  date %s  and: date -u %s, while it returns the same number, so what is the catch in this?

Comment: There is not "catch". The time is just UTC. How it is presented differss due to timezone/day light savings

Answer (score 0):

```
%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

This does not change with the time zone. The calculation is the same.